# put blank value instead of null in array value php

Tags: php

There is dynamic array that we received from database .
It has some null value.

So I want to put empty string instead of null in value

I know, I can check with isset function. But it is dynamic array so it is difficult to find out number of key value pairs.

```
$hoteldetails = get_hotel_detail($hotel_id);
$response=json_encode($HotelDetail);
```

get Hotel details fetching from database. It may have some null value 
Ex- Latitude or longitude can have null. When I encode json_encode it display null.

I also tried array_filter but it is removing null value element. I do not want to remove key value element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PHP Code** (modified from [Replacing empty string with nulls in array php](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12830066/456814)):

```
$array = array(
   'first' => NULL,
   'second' => NULL
);

echo json_encode($array);

$array2 = array_map(function($value) {
   return $value === NULL ? "" : $value;
}, $array); // array_map should walk through $array

echo json_encode($array2);
```

**Output:**

```
{"first":null,"second":null}

{"first":"","second":""}
```

Comment: It is removing key.  I do not want to remove key