# How to filter date 0000-00-00 00:00:00 If user did not enter in my form

Tags: php, mysql, date, strtotime

If users did not enter date MySQL inserts 0000-00-00 00:00:00.
Now I don't want to show date in textbox if its 0000-00-00 00:00:00

I use this helper in codeigniter

```
function dateTimeHelp($date, $mysqlDatetime = true) {
if (strtotime($date) === false)
    return null;
else {
    if ($mysqlDatetime) {
        return date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date));
    } else {
        return date('d-m-Y H:i:s', strtotime($date));
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Related: [Replacing empty string with nulls in array php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12830039/2943403) and [INSERT NULL Values not working instead i get 0.000](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21842500/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple ways, I assume this function is called to display in your form.  Just check for `0000-00-00 00:00:00`:

```
if ($date == '0000-00-00 00:00:00' || strtotime($date) === false)
    return null;
```

Answer (score 1):

what if you change you MySQL column to not null and add the default as current timestamp ?

created_at DATETIME NOT NULL
DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

Using this will mean no code needed and when the form is submitted it will use the date and time that it got put into the database

Comment: If date is not entered in form it will current date its not my requirement